# Isn't filing your CV for three years a little long?

Tags: discussion, jobs

It seems the idea is that you just have a public CV if you are not looking for a job and "file" your CV when you are looking for a job. At the moment you can file your CV for three years! I would be a touch upset, even in the height of a recession, if it took me three years to get a job! Surly this policy is going to end up creating a lot of stale filed CVs which will put off recruiters? Maybe one to six months would be a better time frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expectation is not that it will take you three years to find a job.

Those who opt in early get the benefit of using careers.stackoverflow.com for a job search *at any time* for the next three years. Whether they'll need it or not, that's up to them.

Basically, it is our way of saying "thanks" to those who are willing to be the early adopters.

Comment: Now, *ahem*, about that employer beta. :-D

Comment: If the idea is to give filed CVs more priority with recruiters I would suggest asking people every so often if they still need their CV filed. When I worked on big UK job boards in the past we quite offten got complaints from recruiters about CVs for people that were no longer looing. Just a suggestion, especially as your business seem to be about focusing on quality of CVs rather than quantity.

Answer (score 5):

You never know what's round the corner when it comes to employment. I try to treat my CV as a living document at all times, not just something that gets resurrected whenever I need a new job.

I tend to note all the milestone achievements/projects as they happen. Otherwise I'll forget something important that might have tickled potential employer's fancy. You never know, you might just get an unbelievable offer simply because you keep on top of your CV and keep it fresh and up-to-date. So in short, I don't think three years is a long time to file your CV.

Comment: +1 - even though I don't do this, I know I should. I'm going to cough up the money over the weekend so having paid for it I'll be more likely to keep it up to date.

Comment: @ChrisF: this has been my thinking exactly, except for the past 4 weekends. Weekends have been busy lately... but it's kinda do-it-now time.

Comment: I agree, but isn't your CV being there when you arn't activly looking going to put off a lot of recruiters? It makes their noise to signal ratio far worse

Comment: I don't think so, if you really really aren't interested in a new job then fine, hide it. But, if the job you're in is ok, pays the bills and that's about it, then why not leave yourself open to be head-hunted. Many recruiters already have my CV but the copy they have is always stale, Careers.SO is a great place to keep things up to date.

Comment: @Kev - my thinking exactly.

Answer (score 4):

I will only keep my CV visible until I find a job.

However there are people that are not planning to start looking for a new job yet, they will just hide their CV until they need a new job.  These people can take part in the beta and get the discount due to the 3 year limit.

Also contactors will be looking for me then one contract over a 3 year period.

Comment: It is not clear before you file whether you will be able to hide your CV and then re-file it without paying a second charge. Maybe someone that has coughed up could let us know?

Answer (score 2):

If a person isn't looking for a job, then it's up to them to 'de-publish' it.  But 3 years presents a heck of a cost-savings.  Knowing that if anything happens in the next 3 years that I have a go-to place for having my resume put in front of good hiring managers is quite comforting.

That's what Stack Overflow careers has that other sites do not; the people that hire here are definitely looking for the best.

Comment: But George, what if something happens after 2 years and 10 months? There's no real advantage to signing up for the service now if you aren't looking for a job! I certainly don't want to give my employers the impression that I'm looking for a job when I'm not; just to get a possible $70 saving

Comment: Are people really going to want to defile themselves ;-).

Comment: @oxbow_lakes: Just because your CV is published doesn't mean you're looking for a job. If it were LinkedIn would be a ghost town. You can take yourself out of the search results for managers and still maintain a public CV. That's what I plan on doing.

Comment: I see kev's is already planning not to de-publish. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28841/isnt-filing-your-cv-for-three-years-a-little-long/28854#28854

Answer (score 2):

If something is $99, then you'd like to think that you would definitely only need it once. I think 3 years covers nicely for this - it has the feel of **"the foreseeable future"** about it. i.e. I think it will more than cover my needs for the foreseeable future.

Let's say they had given you 12 months: what if it took you 6 months to find a job, you have 3 months notice (very common in the UK at least) and then you found pretty quickly that the job wasn't what you thought and you want to start looking again?

Answer (score 1):

Refraining from a full quote: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247217/do-you-actively-look-for-a-better-job/247233#247233

I *always* keep my CV up-to-date. Never know when it'll come in handy :)

Answer (score 0):

Joel gave a plug for the launch of careers during the recent DevDays tour:

- I have the impression that the 3-year introduction is their way of seeding the database. In many ways it's a win-win.
- The subscription lets you 'publish' your CV so that searches will find it.
- While the subscription is active you can toggle whether it's published or not.

During the plug Joel mentioned that it should also be possible to blacklist certain employers so that you don't show up in their searches, with the default being all employers on your CV. I can't see any evidence of this feature yet though.